# What property makes a sub-report to grow or shrink?

Tags: ssrs-2012, subreport

Previously when developing in SSRS 2008 I do not recall having any problems with the sub-reports: they grew or shrunk automatically w/o me having to do anything special about that.

Now I am looking at a bunch of reports that were created from Crystal by running some "tool" (I was not told what that tool was). And their sub-reports residing in the tablix cells do not want to grow or shrink.

If a sub-report is larger than the cell it is housed in, only the very first line would show and the rest would be clipped. If the sub-report is empty and I enlarged its parent cell to accommodate the report should it have data, then it would not shrink.

The sub-report objects have no `CanGrow` or `CanShrink` properties, and the tablix cell housing the sub-report would not have a TextBox that would have that property.

I can't assume that MS intended the sub-reports to always have specific size, as that would be terminally stupid, but also cannot find a solution here or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False alarm! The conversion tool has set all cells of any tablix to `CanGrow=False`. There were cells before and after the sub-report cells that caused the sub-reports to have fixed size.

Setting all cells that were of `TextBox` kind to `CanGrow=True` fixed the issue and also fixed clipping of the regular text/numbers of course.